# Poodle Exploit - Disable SSL v3 on a website specific basis

Tags: ssl, iis-7.5, poodle

I'm looking for a very specific situation here with this Poodle exploit.  I have a need to disable SSL v2/3 on a subset of my IIS websites, but leave SSL 2/3 available on a few others.  Is it possible to do this with IIS 7.5?

Comment: As far as I know, on Windows you can only do it system-wide.

Comment: The client first connects via TLS/SSL and then says which website he wants to see.

Comment: @sebix If you are using Per-IP hosting, then the name passed after TLS has been negotiated shouldn't matter.  It seems like it would be useful to have different bound IPs or ports with different TLS settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware the SSL settings in IIS are system wide. I have spent a lot of time on this and the only references I've found are for schannel and system wide.

I've dealt with this in the past by using an Apache instance as a proxy.

I've set this up either running on a separate VM or running on the same server, depending on the client. Using `mod proxy` and per-vhost ssl configuration works well.

When using a single host setup, I adjusted the IIS sites to listen on `localhost` only and the external IP for Apache.

Comment: Thanks for this Tim.  I'll keep that in mind for the near point.